# ecryptfs-setup-swap made a swap that is in clear text to root

Tags: swap, ecryptfs, cryptsetup, dmcrypt

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a MacBook Air, SSD, using LVM without encryption.

The original swap was mapped to `/dev/dm-1`.
After running `ecryptfs-setup-swap`, the new swap was mapped to `/dev/dm-2` and `cryptsetup` status showed that it was active.  `Gnome-disks` identifies both of these volumes as swap with one of them `/dev/dm-1` being inactive.

However, `/dev/dm-2` was still viewable in clear text (for example, via `sudo dd infile=/dev/dm-2`).

Question:  is this the expected outcome after running `ecryptfs-setup-swap`? If so, this implies that data in the swap is still potentially vulnerable.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you mean by "viewable by root"? Partitions and swap space are encrypted only when the computer is off. When you turn the computer on and enter the passphrase they are decrypted. This is like having a padlock on your front door. You can only lock the when you are outside. When you are home, you can't lock the door using a padlock.

Comment: Encryption does not provide any protection while the partitions are decrypted and in use. To test this, boot from a Live Ubuntu installation USB (use the Try Ubuntu option) and try the same clear text example command, without entering the encryption passphrase.